# Is there a way to make a comment in TFS when adding an AD user to a TFS group?

Tags: security, tfs

I was wondering if I can make a comment somewhere in Team Foundation Server when I add an AD user to a TFS group or change the group of the user, for auditing purpose.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to achieve this out of the box.

Comment: Guess I will create a script to run everyday to identify changes to group membership. At least I know which user is added/removed to/from a group at the specific day.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a PowerShell script to record day2day changes to TFS user databases and query the AD to find out who approved this change.
Now we have a self made db.

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth - I wrote a C# method to pull the list of all members from every TFS group. Hope that helps!

EDIT: "**This is posted as an answer because "xidada" was going to write a script to pull the information and since I already had the code to get the information that needed, I thought the code would be a guide to help him/her with the script**"

```
 private void btn_GetNow_Click()
    {
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server/collection"));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

        TfsConfigurationServer srv = tfs.ConfigurationServer;

        CatalogNode configurationServerNode = srv.CatalogNode;

        // Query the children of the configuration server node for all of the team project collection nodes
        ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> tpcNodes = configurationServerNode.QueryChildren(
              new Guid[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
              false,
              CatalogQueryOptions.None
            );

        Guid tpcId = new Guid(tpcNodes[0].Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = srv.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcId);

        // get a reference to the work item tracking service
        var workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        List<Identity> result = new List<Identity>();
        // iterate over the projects
        foreach (Project project in workItemStore.Projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tProject: {0}", project.Name);
            try
            {
                VersionControlServer versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
                TeamProject teamProject = versionControl.GetTeamProject(project.Name);
                IGroupSecurityService gss = (IGroupSecurityService)tpc.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
                Identity[] appGroups = gss.ListApplicationGroups(teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);

                foreach (Identity group in appGroups)
                {
                    rtb_Users.AppendText(group.DisplayName + "\n");
                    Identity[] groupMembers = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, new string[] { group.Sid }, QueryMembership.Expanded);
                    foreach (Identity member in groupMembers)
                    {
                        if (member.Members != null)
                        {
                            foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
                            {
                                Identity memberInfo = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.None);
                                if (memberInfo.Type == IdentityType.WindowsUser)
                                {
                                    if (!result.Contains(memberInfo))
                                    {
                                        result.Add(memberInfo);
                                        rtb_Users.AppendText("\t\t" + memberInfo.AccountName + " - " + memberInfo.DisplayName + " - " + memberInfo.Domain + "\n");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tUser already available " + memberInfo.AccountName);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tThe Project: '{0}' throws an exception: {1} and will be ignored.", project.Name, ex.Message);
            }
        } 
    }
```

**This method is pulled out from my application AS IS and would need to be customized for your needs.**

Comment: Can someone explain why this was downvoted? This was posted as an answer because "xidada" was going to write a script to pull the information and I thought the code would be a guide to help him.